# Memory Leak in iOS when use react native listView

Tags: listview, react-native, memory-leaks

I am using react native listView. In this thousands of record populated now I scroll down the list iOS device memory increase accordingly and after some time app crash in case of android listView is recycled but in iOS listView is not recycled and memory increase. How can I fix this any one help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListView component of React Native has been deprecated because of these memory issues. FlatList and SectionList (if you need sections) are its successors, and are more performant. They can still be a bit buggy at times, but overall they are a great improvement over ListView.

[This blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html) (from March 2017 already) introduces the new list API's.

Comment: Thanks.. I use flatList instead of listView this reduced some of memory as compare to listview